# C# When declaring some variables why do we use "new"?

Tags: c#

For example, declaring a time span we would say:

```
var timeSpan = new TimeSpan();
```

So my first question is, what does the "new" do exactly?

My second question would be, in other cases it's not necessary:

```
var timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
```

I don't understand why the "new" now falls away?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51y09td4.aspx

Comment: The second one will also use `new`, it is just wrapped in a function.

Comment: The source proves @clcto's point: [`FromHours`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/timespan.cs,224) calls an `Interval` method which ends up returning a [`new TimeSpan`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/timespan.cs,236).

Comment: `TimeSpan.FromHours` is just a helper method. It will call `new` inside it. The API author is just being nice so you can avoid writing `new TimeSpan(0, hours, 0, 0, 0)` or `TimeSpan.Interval(someothernumber)` each time you want just the hours.

Answer (score 1):

> So my first question is, what does the "new" do exactly?

Says you want to make a new thing, as simple as that. "Dear C#, please make me a new TimeSpan".

> I don't understand why the "new" now falls away?

Because you aren't creating a new thing, you're asking something else "Dear TimeSpan struct, please give me a TimeSpan".

Now that method can (and in this case, does) create a new object, but it could give you a cached one (pointless with value types, but sometimes useful with immutable reference types) or maybe give you a new object sometimes and one of a cached set for common values (also useful with immutable reference types). That it doesn't **have** to be through `new` is **one** reason why such factory methods might exist.

In **this** case it exists just because it's handy to have a way of turning a number into a `TimeSpan` for a given number of hours, for a given number of days, a given number of seconds, etc. and we can have only one constructor that takes a `double`. If `TimeSpan` had such a constructor then it could only detail how many days **or** how many hours **or** how many seconds etc. You couldn't have `new TimeSpan(3.2)` do one in one call and another the next.

In other cases (with reference types) such *factory* methods can be useful because they don't give you something of the exact type asked, but a derived type, deciding itself which to do.

More often we get new objects of a given type through `new` with a constructor because there isn't anything for a factory method (as methods that exist primarily to return wanted objects are often called) to add.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is the difference between static properties and instance objects.
Using the 'new' creates an instance of the object.
Calling the TimeSpan.FromHours is a static method that returns an instance of TimeSpan that represents the specified number of hours.

Answer (score -1):

`new` creates a "new" object (instance) of a class. This is true of most OOP-based languages. Writing `new Class()` calls the constructor of the class, which can do preliminary setup work and data storage.

In the instances where you don't need it, you're simply calling a static method that calls the constructor behind the scenes with `new`, does some work to it, and returns the new object. This is not a part of the language specifically, but instead a design choice for ease of use.

Microsoft [offers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51y09td4.aspx) [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fa0ab757.aspx) on the `new` keyword and its various uses (more than are listed here—I just posted the relevant bits).

Comment: don't take it personal or get me wrong but I think redirecting him/her to an already answered question or an external link would do.

Comment: Perhaps. Just tried to explain things more simply than I thought an external link would.

Comment: Okay, all good, but I am sure there are a lot of StackOverflow answers for that specific question with a lot of upvotes which means they should be good answers for him/her. Anyway, I was just thinking if we minimise the non-important questions i.e allowing them to be closed would make life easier for all of us to focus on the important "non-repeat" questions.

Comment: I understand entirely. Keeping the quality of questions on the site up is important. I'll keep that in mind for future questions.

Comment: Thank you for understanding. Appreciated!.

Comment: Just to add, I did try and search for this specific type of question for a while and struggled to find one that explains why in some cases I was seeing the new operator being used and in others not. I do appreciate the answers, I think I understand now.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use new when you create a new instance of an object.

Ok, when you just create a variable like below the this creates a pointer in STACK

```
  TimeSpan timeSpan;
```

so till this time there, no memory allocation is done in HEAP and when you initialized with the NEW keyword, HEAP memory allocation is done.

```
  timeSpan = new TimeSpan();
```

you can combine *declaration* and *initialization* in one line as below

```
 var timeSpan = new TimeSpan();
```

In case of static method, you dt need to use new as it is not required to initialize a static (FromHours is a static method of TimeSpan) as show below

```
 var timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
```

Comment: Thanks for going into the memory allocation, added a lot more background to my question. Much appreciated.